# Ошибка "The project you are opening contains compilation errors" при запуске проекта

Tags: unity3d, project

При запуске только что созданного проекта вылетает ошибка: `The project you are opening contains compilation errors`.
Просит войти в safe mode, после которого очередной краш и отправка bug report. 
Не могу работать. Помогите исправить. Пробовал переустанавливать — ноль эффекта. Качал с официального сайта.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас при создании проекта он повредился. Из-за этого юнити и не может открыть проект.

Comment: Получается он повреждается каждый раз,но есть ли в этом причина?

Comment: Если вы столкнулись с такой же проблемой что и я, попробуйте скачать версию unity 5 у меня проект запустился https://unity3d.com/ru/get-unity/download/archive

Comment: Я пайтонист, просто в прошлом на юньке работал